# how to replace display:contents in browser Edge

Tags: css, microsoft-edge, display

So, I have a table with rows where the row height is way bigger than it needs to be. In every browser but Edge, I can fix the problem with display:contents, but in Microsoft Edge, which doesn't support this feature at this time, I have to find an alternative. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mcve], and edit your question accordingly. _“a table with rows where the row height is way bigger than it needs to be”_ - shows us what you did to get into that situation in the first place. I doubt display:contents is the proper way to go about this to begin with.

Comment: Added JS Fiddle Link[link](https://jsfiddle.net/haegensnico/yaxc47n8/2/)

Comment: Please do not just link to external resources, but include relevant code _in_ your question. // The problem seems to disappear, as soon as I remove he fixed height of 300px you put on the tbody ... but I guess you need that, because you are trying to implement some sort of “scrollable” table here? That is notoriously difficult to achieve and to get right … Maybe you can add those styles dynamically after the page has loaded, to give Edge a chance to render the table properly first or something like that.

Comment: I try to add the code in my question, but I can't figure out how to actually do that without violating any of  the constraints put on adding code. You ask for code but then forget to mention what the proper way of formatting is. I took a look at the guide but I didn't get any wiser from it.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I try to check your code with Edge and check the result.
I made change in line below and set 'height: 30 px' instead of 300 px.

```html
  <tbody data-link="row" class="rowlink" style="overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden; height: 30px; display: contents;">
```

Now it is displaying the rows properly in all major browsers including Edge.

Below is the testing result with Edge.

[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGhHT.png)

I think this can be the easiest alternative to display the output properly in Edge.

Regards

Deepak

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following code to your CSS after [your element] that is using display: contents;

```
`@supports not (display: contents) { /* workaround because Edge doesn't support display: contents; */
 a.remove {
    display: inline;
 }
}`
```

Replace a.remove with your element name.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not yet implemented by edge browser and IE.
Basically there are two ways the break the flex-row

1)Page-break(Works only in Mozilla)

2) display: contents;(Works only in Mozilla,Chrome).

So if know number of rows and have repeated instances to break could use display:block and inline to get the required result.
But in dynamically repeating rows and number of tiles available its not possible to break the flex box.
Kindly report Edge browser to implement display: contents.
https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/10938981-implement-the-box-generation-keywords-from-css-dis
which is very important feature and missed out.